# Merging MbUnit and NUnit tests and displaying in CruiseControl

Tags: xslt, ant, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol, mbunit

We have a CruiseControl server running various AntUnit, MbUnit and NUnit tests via Ant.

In order to merge the outputs from them all we have the following in the CruiseControl config:

```
<log dir="logs/${project.name}/">
  <merge dir="${q7.build.tests.dir}/reports" pattern="*.xml" />
  <merge dir="${q7.build.tests.dir}/reports" pattern="**/*.html" />
</log>
```

This works, however MbUnit outputs the tests in a different XML format than NUnit and AntUnit. For example, NUnit seems to use <testcase> to signify a test result whereas MbUnit uses <run> among other things.

Does anyone know how to transform the MbUnit output into NUnit compatible format XML that we can then merge together to produce a full set of test reports by applying the NUnit unittests.xsl?

Comment: The required transformation could be written if you provide the formats of MBUnit tests and NUnit tests. Ideally, you could provide a very small XML instance of an MBUnit test and the wanted result (as an XML instance of an NUnit test) with direction which data goes into which output.

Comment: I was going to say that same thing.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Gallio to run both your MbUnit and NUnit tests then the output will be in the same format and you can use the Gallio reports.

Alternately just modify your Dashboard.config file to include the MbUnit report in addition to the NUnit report.